# Emigrate to a foreign country with a remote US-based job

Tags: usa, immigration, indian-citizens, working

Background:

I have received job offer from a US-based company and the entire work force is remote. I'm indian by nationality. The company doesn't mind where I work out of, as long as I'm available in EST hours.

If I want to work from the US, they are willing to sponsor an H1B visa.

Question:
Is it possible to move to a country like Canada, New Zeland or Ireland, as I will be working remotely, so technically I have a job in that country?

Please point me to the resources. I'm interested in applying for a Canada visa.

I have no relatives in any countries but India.
I have a MS from a US university.

Answer (score -1):

Unlikely any country (except USA) will make a decision to allow you to immigrate based on your US job. So you need to separate your intent to immigrate and your US job.

Start working in your home country, and earn some money. Then, you can apply for a Canadian immigration and pay the (hefty) fee. Decision to admit you will be made regardless of your US job offer, so you might look how many points you will get for your age, profession etc. and how likely you will succeed. Once in Canada, you can work for US company on TN visa. You may want to talk to Canadian embassy about this, and tell them you have secured job in USA, but will be contributing to Canadian economy by paying Canadian taxes.

As a bonus, if something goes wrong with your US job, you can stay and work in Canada.

Comment: He won't qualify for a TN visa until he's been in Canada long enough as a Permanent Resident to become a Canadian citizen, but that is also kind of irrelevant since he doesn't need any US status to work for a US company if he is living and doing the work somewhere else.

Comment: @Dennis Don't people emigrating via Express Entry become permanent residents immediately?

Comment: @Dennis - but OP **wanted** to immigrate to Canada. I agree with you (and wrote in my answer) that OP needs to separate his work and his immigration plans.  I am not sure if having US-based job will gain him any points for Canadian immigration. And yes, OP can work for that company even without TN visa, but TN allows him to switch the jobs.